# composer.json does not contain valid JSON

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I want to run `composer update` on my laravel project but I keep getting this error:

```
[Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
  "./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON
  Parse error on line 1:

  ^
  Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

I have validated my `composer.json` on **www.jsonlint.com** and the json is valid. I don't know what could be the cause.

**My composer.json**

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "anhskohbo/no-captcha": "^2.4",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
    "intervention/image": "^2.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^5.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
        ]
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
}
}
```

Comment: I tried your composer.json by coping into mine and run `composer update` got no error. May be there is some undesired special character in your file check it or just copy from here and replace your current one and use `composer update`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your ***composer.json*** file according to this:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
             "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
             "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
     }
}
```

After Changes of **composer.json** file, must be run this command: `composer update`

---

To install the most recent version, run the following command:

- For [intervention/image](https://packagist.org/packages/intervention/image) package: `composer require intervention/image`
- For [laravel/socialite](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/socialite) package: `composer require laravel/socialite`
- For [No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA](https://packagist.org/packages/anhskohbo/no-captcha) package: `composer require anhskohbo/no-captcha`
- For [laravelcollective/html](https://packagist.org/packages/laravelcollective/html) package: `composer require laravelcollective/html`
- For [stripe/stripe-php](https://packagist.org/packages/stripe/stripe-php) package: `composer require stripe/stripe-php`

**NOTE:** This will download latest version of your laravel project

Comment: Actually I just reload a previous version of this file.